# What is an Introspective Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Introspective Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Introspective Words™ | Not Introspective Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| BRIEF | LONG |
| CLEAR | FUZZY |
| COMMON | RARE |
| COMPLETE | INCOMPLETE |
| ELOQUENT | MOVING |
| ENGLISH | FRENCH |
| ESOTERIC | SECRET |
| ISOGRAM | PANGRAM |
| MEANINGFUL | RANDOM |
| NOUN | VERB |
| SIMPLE | COMPLEX |
| UNAMBIVALENT | CONFUSED |
| UNHYPHENATED | HYPHENATED |
| WEE | LARGE |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Introspective Words™,Not Introspective Words™
BRIEF,LONG
CLEAR,FUZZY
COMMON,RARE
COMPLETE,INCOMPLETE
ELOQUENT,MOVING
ENGLISH,FRENCH
ESOTERIC,SECRET
ISOGRAM,PANGRAM
MEANINGFUL,RANDOM
NOUN,VERB
SIMPLE,COMPLEX
UNAMBIVALENT,CONFUSED
UNHYPHENATED,HYPHENATED
WEE,LARGE
```

Comment: introspective leads me to think that its something to do with the words themselves, but more in the middle of them - like the middle letters form words or something

Comment: Assuming MOehm's answer is right, very clever.  Nicely worked out and presented!

Comment: I like how there is a CSV version that you can run your analysis programs on to lead you down the garden path.

Comment: Yay this series makes a comeback!

Comment: Does the order the words are listed in matter, for example is "brief" the introspective version of "long" or is there no relationship between "brief" and "long"?

Comment: @Celeritas The words were merely listed alphabetically on the left and paired with some related word on the right. However, making the rule be a relationship between words in the table is am interesting idea for a different puzzle.

Comment: @HankyPanky JLee started the trademarking, actually, and I just continued in their format. However, I really am an engineer although I am not really toast.

Comment: @MOehm:  Note that it’s considered anti-social to post text as images without also posting it as text.  Blind people can use the Internet, but (apparently) software that can extract characters from pixels isn’t widely available.  You’ll find that Only Connect and Sudoku puzzles are often posted both as image(s) and as machine-readable text.

Comment: @PeregrineRook: I agree that text versions are usually posted to make the post accessibile, but here, the text version is introduced with "And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version".

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think that Introspective Word™ is another name for ...

> ... [autological word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word), a word that describes a property that it has or, more or less, a word that describes itself.

For example:

> "Brief" is a short word, but "long" isn't a long word. "Noun" is a noun, but "verb" isn't a verb; it's a noun, too. "English" is an English word, but "French" isn't a French word and so on.
>
>  Some cases are a bit more complicated, but they work, too: "Simple" is a simple word, but the word "complex" itself isn't complex. Both "unambivalent" and "confused" are unambivalent; both "meaningful" and "random" are meaningful and both "complete" and "incomplete" are complete. I'm not so sure about "eloquent" and "esoteric", though.

Comment: I dunno, if "verbing weirds language" I think it's fair to say that 'conjugation verbs nouns' and therefor verb is a perfectly valid verb :)

Comment: @Sconibulus: You're right, the online OED has it as "Use (a word that is not conventionally used as a verb, typically a noun) as a verb". But for the sake of this answer, let's say that the usual use of "verb" is as a noun. (It's interesting that the noun/verb line is the only one that doesn't use adjectives.)

Comment: That wasn't a serious objection, more of an excuse to reference Calvin and Hobbes than anything else

Comment: I used the [Wiktionary list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_autological_terms) as a source so there's a grain of salt in its value. `Esoteric` is a not a word I hear used often although its meaning is typically understood. `Eloquent` was a bit of a stretch but I liked how it's a synonym with `moving` when describing a speech but their other definitions are where the autological / heterological differences arise: "clearly expressing or indicating something" vs. "in motion".

Comment: @Sconibulus The [source I used](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_autological_terms) *does* list `verbify` which was moved to "Other parts of speech" on 2005-07-12 because, I presume, the editors weren't sure what to do with it.

Comment: The concept of autological words depends a lot on context, too: Blue is only autological when written in blue. When I pick words randomly from a dictionary and I pick "random", it's autological. So there's a bit of latitude in interpretaion of at least some words.